# Invoking a .ps1 from shared location remotely by passing a local parameter

Tags: powershell, remote-server, unc

I have a set of 10 VMs on which I have to execute some tests. Users will be able to trigger the drive script (1.ps1) from any Local m/c or VM. There is a data set, test DLL and an additional script (2.ps1) placed on a shared drive. 2.ps1 accepts a local parameter. I want to call 2.ps1 from 1.ps1 by passing a parameter.
Execution policy is unrestricted, UNC path is mapped. remoting is enabled.

I have tried the following, with no success:

$scriptPath = '\\$ip2\path\2.ps1'

```
#1
Invoke-Command -computername $ip -ScriptBlock{$scriptPath -PARAM $param} -Credentials $cred

#2
Invoke-Command -computername $ip -ScriptBlock{param($param) $scriptPath -PARAM $param} -ArgumentList $param -Credentials $cred

#3
Invoke-Command -computername $ip -ScriptBlock{$using:scriptPath -PARAM $using:param} -Credentials $cred
```

Content of 2.ps1:

```
param (
    [string]$RUNSETTINGS,
    [string]$VERSION
    #[string]$COMPUTER
)
$env:TEST_HOME = "\\$ip\FMLTestBed\MasterData"
$testDLL = Join-Path $env:TEST_HOME "Test.dll"

$verFolder = "TEST_" + $VERSION
$SettingFile = Join-Path (Join-Path (Join-Path $env:TEST_HOME "TestsInput") $verFolder) "test.runsettings"

$vstestPath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe"
&$vstestPath $testDLL /Settings:"$SettingFile"
```

Can anyone please help me with the right approach?

Comment: How is PowerShell to know where to find `2.ps1`? Remember, unlike CMD, PowerShell does _not_ look in the current location for scripts or legacy executables; it only looks in the folders named in `$env:Path`.

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: @JeffZeitlin I am providing full path to 2.ps1 in a variable:
$scriptpath = \\ip\path\2.ps1

Comment: Your examples do not show the use of `$scriptpath`; they are using the script name `2.ps1` directly. Are your actual calls using the `$scriptpath` variable? Is `path` defined as a share on the computer at `\\ip`?

Comment: @Jeff, please refer the edit.. thanks!

Comment: Is `\path` declared as a share on computer `\\ip`? Are you getting an actual error message? What is the content of `2.ps` - is it actually written to handle passed parameters? You need to provide sufficient information so that a member who is so inclined can attempt to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Jeff, thanks for your interest and help! \\ip is added to UNC path, the folders in \path are shared. The error is that the parameter does not get read when passed from invoke-command.

Comment: Then it looks like you will need to post the code of `2.ps1` to enable further troubleshooting - this is beginning to look like a problem with the script itself, rather than the invocation. (Really, you should have done that from the first, or built a minimal script that exhibits the same problem and posted the code from that.)